# incercept $http request to modify api call urls

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-http-interceptors

```
var app = angular.module('app');
// register the interceptor as a service
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q ) {
    return {

        'request': function(config) {
            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

I am trying to modify the urls of api calls and append the api url to the start of the ajax calls in the interceptor insted of each service function like

```
    function getAssesmentResults(params) {

        return $http.get(url.api + '/results', {params: params})
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    }
```

However the interceptor intercepts all http requests like .css or .html or .json files. What is a good way to modify the urls in the interceptor without modifying other http requests?

Comment: Do all of your API calls have something in common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$http` has a facility to intercept and rewrite URLs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) that is configured on the `$httpProvider`.  When I run in production, I have an extra token: '/rest/' compared with development mode and I detect production mode ( prefix `packing` ) in the interceptor.  This is in my `app.js`

```
var rest_srvr = 'http://dev-pc.example.com:8000'
app.factory('REST_Interceptor',[
        '$location',
function($location) {
  var request = function(config) {
    if (RegExp('packing','i').test(window.location.host)) {
      return config
    }
    var rest_request_regex = new RegExp('^.*?/rest/(.*)$')
    //console.log('config.url=%s',config.url)
    config.url = config.url.replace(rest_request_regex,rest_srvr+'/$1')

    var files_request_regex = new RegExp('^/(files/(.*))$')
    config.url = config.url.replace(files_request_regex,rest_srvr+'/$1')
    //console.log('  is now config.url=%s',config.url)
    return config
  }

  var translate_subpath = function(subpath) {
    return request({url:'https://'+$location.host()+subpath}).url 
  }

  return {
    request: request,
    translate_subpath: translate_subpath
  }
}])

app.config([
          '$httpProvider','$cookiesProvider',
  function($httpProvider,  $cookiesProvider) {
    if (!RegExp('packing','i').test(window.location.host)) {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('REST_Interceptor')
    }
}])
```

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong. so i believe u are suggesting to use something like this. so basically i will append the api url path to api calls but calls to static resources will not be modified                                                                                                                          if(response.config.url.startsWith('/api/')) {
        //Do your custom processing here
  }

Comment: Exactly. That's what lines like `var files_request_regex = new RegExp('^/(files/(.*))$')` and `config.url = config.url.replace(files_request_regex,rest_srvr+'/$1')` do.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a service that wraps the `$http`. Then in your code you'll always call this wrap instead of `$http` and will be able to do whatever you want with the request before it is sent. Just a simple example:

```
module.factory('myHttp', function($http){
  return {
    get: function(url, params){
      var newUrl = "base-api-url/" + url;
      return $http.get(newUrl, params);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic service for this:

**Generic service**

```
appCless.factory("$comum", function($http, $q, $injector) {
    function ajax(url, parametros, metodo) {
        var requisicao = $http({
            method: metodo,
            url: url,
            data:parametros
        });

        var promessa = requisicao.then(
            function(resposta) {
                return(resposta.data);
            },
            function(resposta) {
                return($q.reject("Something went wrong"));
            }
        );
        return promessa;
    }
    return({
        ajax:ajax
    });
});
```

**Service**

```
app.factory("$categoriaproduto", function($comum) {
    var categoria;
    return {
        buscar : function(neoId) {
            var promessa = $comum.ajax("/fusion/services/roi/category/product/search", "", "POST");
            promessa.then(function(req) {  
                categoria = req.data;
            });
            return promessa;
        },
        cache : function() {
            return categoria;
        }
    };
});
```